# Osx: delete all first line of multiple files

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, sed

i read a lot of threads about my question, but i cannot figure out how resolve my problem.

I have a lot of wordpress files that start with a wrong first line. I think my wordpress was hacked, and every .php file starts with a long set of functions, only in the first line.

I tried to delete the first line of every file via terminal, with sed.

I run this command

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" | xargs sed -i '' '1d'
```

But removes only the first line on the first file; i don't know why.

Hope it's not an already answered question.

Thank in advance.

Comment: xargs passes as many of its arguments as will fit into a command line on to the command you're trying to execute. you're essentially trying to do `sed -i '' '1d' file1 file2 file3 file4 ...fileN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to go for `xargs`, find's builtin function `-execdir` will help you to run an external command on find itself.

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -execdir sed -i '1d' {} \;
```

OR

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -execdir sed -i '' '1d' {} \;
```

Comment: Yes, i try your code with -i '' because in osx we must specify -i file extension even if blank. Thanks a lot !